# Abstract Factory for custom Validators - options discarded?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

My goal is to pass custom options to validators, as is done by the ZF2-provided validators.  Consider this validator config:

`'filters' => array(
                'leaderboard'  => array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'filters'  => array(
                        array('name' => 'stringtrim'),
                    ),
                    'validators' => array(
                        array(
                            'name'    => '\LDP\Form\Validator\UniqueAtom',
                            'options' => array(
                                'key' => 'foo',
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),`

In this case, my validator is provided by an abstract factory which is specified in my application's getValidatorConfig().  It seems though, judging by lines 95+ in AbstractPluginManager that this function sequence ignores creation options:

```
public function get($name, $options = array(), $usePeeringServiceManagers = true)
{
    // Allow specifying a class name directly; registers as an invokable class
    if (!$this->has($name) && $this->autoAddInvokableClass && class_exists($name)) {
        $this->setInvokableClass($name, $name);
    }

    $this->creationOptions = $options;
    $instance = parent::get($name, $usePeeringServiceManagers);
    $this->creationOptions = null;
    $this->validatePlugin($instance);
    return $instance;
}
```

In short, the creation options make their way there, but they're never ferried about.  What's the best solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After banging my head against a wall for a very long time, I've just found the solution in the source.  You have to make your factory implement `Zend\ServiceManager\MutableCreationOptionsInterface`

You can then use whatever it passes to instantiate the "next thing".  Feels like an official band-aid hehe, but it works.

Hope this helps.